# Proving theorem by induction or other form

Tags: summation, induction

Is there a way I can prove this theorem by induction. Or is there another way to prove. 
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty }\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^n 1 = \frac11$$

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty }\frac 1{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac12$$

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty }\frac 1{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^n {k^2} = \frac13$$

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty }\frac 1{n^4}\sum_{k=1}^n {k^3} = \frac14$$

Theorem:
 $$ \lim_{n\to +\infty } \frac 1{n^m}\sum_{k=1}^n k^{m-1} = \frac1m$$
What is the proof for this so that it can work for all numbers.

Comment: you're summing on $i$ but the expression being summed in all but the last line is just $k$. Do you mean to sum $k$ from $1$ to $n$? And do you mean to sum $k^{m-1}$ from $1$ to $n$ for $m = 1, \ldots, 4$ in the first four lines?

Comment: I edited the problem. I apologize about that mistake.

Comment: It helps to know $$\sum_{k = 1}^{n} k^m = \sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1} \bigg( \left(\sum_{k = 1}^n k^{m - 1}\right) - \left(\sum_{k = 1}^j k^{m - 1}\right)\bigg)$$ combine that with $\sum_{k=1}^n k^m \in \Theta(n^{m+1})$

Answer (score 3):

As said in comments, powers of $k$ were missing in most expressions you wrote (except in the first one).

The easiest is to compare to Riemann sums 
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty } \frac 1{n^m}\sum_{k=0}^n k^{m-1}=\lim_{n\to +\infty } \frac 1{n}\sum_{k=0}^n \left(\frac k n\right)^{m-1}=\int_0^1x^{m-1}\,dx=\frac 1 m$$ Otherwise, you could use [Faulhaber's formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) and look at the limit when $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Can you explain that last part when you reach the integral?